# Linked answer, link gone, code missing - should the answer go as well?

Tags: discussion

I have a decision question. It's an early, peaceful morning and I'm redacting Q&A material on the site as I run over it.

This also includes checking for links and updating them, for example in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3797354/367456

However, just seeing that the linked example is missing nowadays. Should the answer now go away as well - or that part of the answer? Or should the cruft be kept on the website? Should it be annotated? Just downvoted?

Answer (score 3):

Actually you took a correct action by [editing and fixing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3797354/revisions) the correct link.

If we find some dead links in good answers we can take the following action:

- If you know the correct link fix them by editing (which you did)
- If you don't know the correct link comment to the answer and ask the author to correct it.
- If the author doesn't fix it or doesn't response you and answer becomes invalid due to those dead link, flag it for moderator's attention and request them to take further steps.

A moderator can either

- fix the link (if they know)
- remove that link from the answer if the answer remains valid even after the removal of the link
- remove the answer (if it is link only answer).

Comment: Just to add. Dead link can be found by: 1) Internet Archive 2) Google for the dead link 3) Goodle for part of the dead link, and check the correlation of content of the new link.

Comment: The answer is not "good". Fixing the link lead to no-where as the code-example is not available. Also checking with internet archive didn't reveal anything useful. I start to get puzzled.

Comment: Link is now gone completely, question reworded. Could not dig out any fitting example for that original link in any archive.

Answer (score 0):

If an answer is/was only Link only answer, that will be flagged, resulting in deletion by moderators.

An answer may contain Links for further explanation, but the answer should be complete enough without the link.

Comment: Okay, that's helpful feedback. A second part is just suggesting "an alternative" and as well only outlining with a link. I think I'll write a code-example my own, add it as an answer and flag the existing one - or just edit it which would spare the moderators some work even it may be seen as hijacking the "answer".

Comment: I have copied few contents from the link and edited the answers. Also many times I have flagged the answer as LOA(Link only answer). Even you can write your own answer, but if a question is say 1 year old and answer is already accepted then your answer may not get attention from people.